# How to force VS Code to provide hints in Python when there is a syntax error?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Any sort of syntax error near the cursor causes the VS Code Python extension to stop providing hints:

[image: Editor behaviour]

Here, I'm ready to type the closing parenthesis as soon as I'm done typing the variable name, which the editor refuses to help with.

How can I stop this exasperating behavior?

Comment: there is no need for the yellow `(` in python, it is not C/C++

Comment: fix the expression, then you get an error for variable unknown, and you can fix that with a completion (Ctrl+Space)